Sharepoint API permissions in Entra App are not working ie Full control granted with admin consent over the tenant but access denied
I can connect via PnP online using a certificate successfully but to perform any actions I get access denied.
This is despite having full control or read and write (I tried both) permissions via the application approach. Even trying to add permissions to certain sites results in access denied.
I'm at a loss here. How can I have no access?

Since September 9, there is a change with PnP PowerShell connection. Did you follow the new setup? https://pnp.github.io/blog/post/changes-pnp-management-shell-registration/

@jleture yes this is the new set up, I followed the video that the PnP developer made, created the app registry via powershell and assigned permissions at the same time
